# Communication exception when calling Java webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I have developed an Java webservice which will make an RMI call to update Oracle database. This web service is consumed by .Net windows service and call the service to update data in database. At sometime when number of transaction increases(at peak load) I'm getting below exception from the web service. The endpoint that webservice exposing is using basichttpbinding.

I have been trying to fix this issue or revisit the architecture to avoid such exception. Can anyone tell me how to avoid such exceptions.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error (The request was aborted: The request was canceled.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStreamAsyncResult.CompleteGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb6dccd4-a065-45ff-bf42-ac423f6ba707/communication-exception-when-calling-java-webservice?forum=architecturegeneral